# Sides of a polygon

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, grid, pattern-matching

Given an ASCII-art shape made of the characters `/\|_`, your challenge is to return the number of sides it has.

A side is a straight line of one of those, for example:

```
\
 \
  \

 /
/

|
|
|
|

_____
```

Are all sides.

For example, this shape:

```
  ___
 /   \
/_____\
```

Has *four* sides. You can assume the input will be a single valid, closed shape - that is, things like this:

```
/
 _
/ \

 \
/

/_\
\_/
 _   _
/_\ /_\
```

Will *not* occur, and the shape will never touch itself, so this is invalid:

```
  /\/\
 / /\ \
/ /__\ \
|______|
```

### Testcases:

```
 /\
/__\ -> 3

 ________
/        \
|_________\  -> 5

___
|_| -> 4

/\/\/\/\/\
|________| -> 13

 _   _
| |_| |
|  _  | -> 12
|_| |_|
          
         /\
        /  \
   /\  /    \    /\
  /  \/      \  /  \
 /            \/    \
/____________________\ -> 7

   _
  / |
 _| |
/___/ -> 8
```

Comment: 10/10 testcases, especially the last one

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 49 bytes

*-1 thanks to Jonah*

This answer has 6 sides.

```
[:+/@,i.@4(1==-{&(0 1,1,.i:1)@[|.!.0=)"{'_/|\'&i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBDoIwDL33KyoHYBE2MJ5GlpCYePLklZkdjChe/AD679hNQBP3lmVtX/va7jklMuvRaMywwAo131Li4Xw6Tp3eqrYYZLvPa2PKMc0rrIu6kIOuRduR3MjKiGTMnCKbpYOcBNyNvl0frza/ND172DXS7TAPwgJQWVDOWRDwz7kZoHCGBVqC8RqfTY5ilLLL@YpQvC93YhlkISR@fYAgeNEKXAGrxV1W088dQsFmb03w1LycXRIV/uDDhj/6R/zX/Oxei3gRP78vVSCmNw)

- `'_/|\'&i.` Map walls to 0…4.
- `i.@4` For each possible wall …
- `|.!.0=` shift the corresponding bitmap …
- `{&(0 1,1,.i:1)@[` into the direction the wall points to.
- `1==-` Subtract this from the original bitmap and keep the 1s.
- `[:+/@,` Count the 1s.

Example for the `_`-lines in

```
____
|__|   original
 ____
 |__|  shifted by 1 into a direction _ points to

X....  spots where _ is in the original image,
.X...  but not in the shifted one.
```

Two Xs, thus two `_`-lines.

Comment: Very clever solution!  Might want to add a picture of a shape before and after expansion, to show off the key central idea visually.

Comment: @Jonah thanks & done!

Comment: `0>.` -> `1=` seems to work for -1

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 94 bytes

```
(?<=(.)*)(\|(?=.*¶(?<-1>.)*\|)|\\(?=.*¶(?<-1>.)*.\\)|/(?=.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?<-1>/)))(?(1)^)
 
_+|\S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU87DsIwDN19ikgRUgyiVndKD9HVImVgYGFAjD5XD9CLBdv9ofIy5Pm9F9t5Pz7P172MA0To@hjhkPoI41BSe2lShUdMLKltquM4qHSur6qxoDDv1YoZhfbqRAgRU5tqvCEEyCfhrpRADJQzA4Q8AyjMYJBFtIR5kgWAeDlbQKyDvtFI0FAQvU0Q8Mr9FRvVFiu1gS4512oNmDVvxUuQwg8m17/yD/bR2fuIbmnLWZC@)
Link includes test suite that takes double-spaced test cases. Explanation:

```
(?<=(.)*)(\|(?=.*¶(?<-1>.)*\|)|\\(?=.*¶(?<-1>.)*.\\)|/(?=.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?<-1>/)))(?(1)^)
```

Match any of `|`, `\` or `/` with the corresponding symbol on the next line, but indented to line up with it and replace it with a space. (This is slightly golfier than using negative lookaheads.)

```
_+|\S
```

Count any remaining non-whitespace, except a run of `_` only counts as one side.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 42 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⪫υ⸿θＰθＦθ⎇№⁺ ⊟ＫＤ²✳⊕｜⌕/|\ι⁴ιψι≔ＬＫＡθ⎚Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5PS8QwEMXv/RRDThOoBMTbntaVhRXFgh4DUrpjOxiTmj8uC373mrTurgffJe83b4a8bmh951ozTYeBDQHu7Jjic/Rse5QSmhQGTDWwXFXrELi3eO/YlpHQXsgaPnPymEzkMd9ELPjmPGQDzTx5IW9bf8SNS5kakwIKEDU0bsSG6P2OPXWRncXrGi6ws52nD7KR9njL8cCBnjxu2e5RqG@tRSlVw42ctcCxPJemD2T7OMyfrI1B@dt2Y6j1mM3Sb9OGUluupglOUro6W4AZlJ59pvNCidSypU@LCv5oSXWlXv@RrqarL/MD) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the list of strings.

```
≔⪫υ⸿θ
```

Join them with carriage returns.

```
Ｐθ
```

Print the result to the canvas without moving the cursor.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over each character.

```
⎇№⁺ ⊟ＫＤ²✳⊕｜⌕/|\ι⁴ιψι
```

If the character is a space or equal to the adjacent character in the appropriate direction (E, SE, S or SW as appropriate), then erase it, otherwise reprint it.

```
≔ＬＫＡθ
```

Count the number of remaining characters on the canvas.

```
⎚Ｉθ
```

Clear the canvas and output the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 598 bytes:

```py
import re
def f(b,c,l,s=[]):
 k=0
 for u,v in{'/':[[-1,1],[1,-1]],'\\':[[1,1],[-1,-1]]}[l]:
  if(x:=c[0]+u)>=0 and(y:=c[1]+v)>=0 and(x,y)not in s:
   try:
    if b[x][y]==l:k=1;yield from f(b,(x,y),l,s+[(x,y)])
   except:1
 if k==0:yield tuple(sorted(s))
def g(b):
 b=[*filter(None,b.split('\n'))]
 e=enumerate;S=set;R=sum;L=len
 t=[((x,y),j) for x,a in e(b)for y,j in e(a)if j=='/'or j=='\\']
 n={m for i in t for m in f(b,i[0],i[-1],[i[0]])}
 return R(not any(S(i)&S(j)==S(i)and L(j)>L(i)for j in n)for i in n)+R(L(re.findall('_+',i))for i in b)+R(L(re.findall('\|+',''.join(i)))for i in zip(*b))
```

Very simple algorithm: find the number of diagonal edges (using `f`), and then the number of horizontal and vertical edges (using `re.findall`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLbbqMwEH33V1h5WOzGCaHXVSL3C6J9aB8BodCYrlNiEDhV2NJv787YhKLdiRLmHJ8zzIxTd/Z3ZW5@1s3Xlz7WVWNpo8heFbRguXgRpWhlnPI1oW9yRWhRNfQk3qk2H0EYrON4EYkoFXEkFlGaiiBJkPTcwpOfcZmCneqCndfyJV6l8xN/lCu6M3vWIROl8/eROYuOm8rCG2iLNmqbzj2hAM3jcxp3qZTl@k1Gm06rck@Lpjq6bp0XO57HLk05@tT5RdV2HREs8Cblau1t9lSXirUwsdqzlnM39CvLcdZcxleFLq1q2K/KKJEv27rUlgWJCThPCVVSmdNRNTurNs@yVXbzJNvTcbOVpTKEWhkz382Bu52dxQ4nUlAeYScOHu44NHWQEpYJNCawQahv5MfRGTXqrEuPmOKcGnYIPwtcMuYp/yRwa/bUGPrEcHk707FnpvmPZ3bgUmIKu6VbQI9bAFjOdWD4@BLD509syxq1LLTZ78qSBdk8EJp/S/L/JUkPmiBYHiptoPBE/EfX7Crn/KuVs9kMbiLLMkJDuJEEviTMMBJK8LCNvCZMkE88d@25bAiCVhfop6S/HECRocqNc6C2z3pP3ToqTC6fiW9Q3A2vgZoZnFKw0h6eyPTEoYv0fphkiDChkxj5cOhweoDScOx9YiReH46TDW6/qTGS0Tws7p@47PHh0mHmK/fwwAm8LfSqutHGslf3px/zaAqup@BmCm6n4G4K7qfgAe79Lw)